# What are all the options available to capture Ubuntu installation and later restore to a pristine condition?

Tags: backup, restore, disk-image

For testing, I have been using an Ubuntu Server VM on a Windows machine under VMware and disabling persistent storage. After a reboot I'm back to the original machine configuration. It's really straightforward for me to return to a pristine configuration which includes some minimal tools.

Now that I have a separate machine dedicated to this task, I was wondering if I could avoid using VMs or Docker since my installation needs aren't too complex. The only issue is that my changes touch files in /etc/ and elsewhere that make blowing everything away preferable. Is there an alternative to [backing up and restoring the machine with dd](https://www.codepunker.com/blog/how-to-backup-ubuntu-and-restore-it-using-dd)?

My problem with dd is that I need to boot it with other media to be able to restore the original image. I'd like for it to be as simple as running a script. Taking time to restore isn't too big a deal, but I want it to run as headless as possible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can create a backup system with clonezilla. You create an image of the partition, save in in another partition, install clonezilla and add it to the grub menu. When you need to restore, just go to the clonezilla entry. This is an example, is this what you need?

Comment: Yeah if I could choose at boot run clonezilla that'd be helpful.

Comment: I'll try to write an answer then, not presently... but soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Restore system using clonezilla

Download:

- Clonezilla ISO image.
- Clonezilla ZIP.

#### Setup

1. Clone an image of the desired partition(s) with Clonezilla, saving it in an secondary or external disk¹. Note the size of the image.
2. Create a partition big enough to store the image created and the Clonezilla extracted ZIP. Note the partition number.
3. Extract the contents of the Clonezilla ZIP file in the created partition.
4. Add to the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` the following code, replacing the X in `msdosX` for the partition number, example `msdos2`:

   ```
   menuentry "Restore" {
      set root='hd0,msdos2'
      linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=en ocs_live_run="sudo bash /lib/live/mount/medium/restore" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=788 ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
      initrd /live/initrd.img
    }
   ```
5. Run `sudo update-grub`.
6. Clone an image, again, of the desired partition(s) with Clonezilla, saving it in the partition created.

#### Create Clonezilla's command file

Run Clonezilla and start to perform a restore partition task with the created image. When asked if sure to continue, say no. Enter the Clonezillas's command-line and copy the generated file with the command that was about to be executed. Paste it in the root created partition. Note the name, it will be used in the next script.

```
sudo su -
cp /tmp/ocs-restore-<some date> /lib/live/mount/medium/
reboot
```

#### Clonezilla's script

Create a bash script named `restore` in the root of the partition created with the following code²:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

bye() {
  local rp=(r p)
    while true;  do
    echo -e "\e[33mReboot/Poweroff [r/p]\e[0m"
    read repo
    if [[ ! "${rp[@]}" =~ "$repo" ||  -z "$repo" ]] ; then
      echo "Press 'r' or 'p'..."
      continue
    else
      break
    fi
  done
    case "$resh" in
    r) reboot;;
    s) poweroff
  esac
}

ask() {
  clear
  local yn=(y n)
    while true;  do
    echo -e "\e[33mAre you sure you want to restore? All saved data will be lost. [y/n]\e[0m"
    read yesno
    if [[ ! "${yn[@]}" =~ "$yesno" ||  -z "$yesno" ]] ; then
      echo "Press 'y' or 'n'..."
      continue
    else
      break
    fi
  done
    case "$yesno" in
    # here the name of the file with the command
    y) /lib/live/mount/medium/ocs-restore-<a date>;;  
    n) bye
  esac
}

[[ ! -f /home/partimag/restore ]] && ln -s /lib/live/mount/medium/home/partimag/restore /home/partimag/restore

ask
```

#### Finalization

Reboot and you should have a GRUB entry named "Restore", it will execute Clonezilla with your script, starting, after asking, the restoring of the system.

---

<sup>¹ Why? Clonezilla' images are proportional to *the data* of the partition, not *the size* of it. So the image will be smaller than the *cloned* partition's size. This is crucial to set the *restore* partition's size.</sup>

<sup>² With some understandig of bash, the code can be changed to whatever is needed or desired.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The application "Timeshift" is designed to take "snapshots" of the system files, so one can restore the system to a previous state. It probably will fit your user case.

Timeshift is available for installation in Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 0):

Same drawback as your current approach - need to boot with other media - but [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is my go-to solution.